# AVL TREE Malloc Functionwhen inserting a new node

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, avl-tree, null-pointer

I recently created a bst successfully in C..Then my attempt was 
to create an AVL..The first step in doing so .Was to add a extra
component bf(balance factor ) in every node..I did it as follows.

```
    struct tnode{
        int info;
        struct tnode*left;
        struct tnode*right;
        int bf;//new field for avl tree..
                };
```

Everytime malloc assigns a address to new node while insertion...I assign its info part to
the value entered by user..set the left and right pointer to NULL.In addition to this it assigns the bf
of the newnode to 0..After insertion of first node(ie root node) program fails at the malloc part next time to
even assign a memory to the newnode...As soon as I remove the part which says newnode->bf=0..The problem vanishes..
Why is this happening ?.Below is my main function and add() function which takes integer as input and insert it to tree with root node as 'root' declared globally.

```
    int main(){
    int choice,val;
    deci:
    printf("\n1.Insert");
    printf("\n2.Display");
    printf("\n3.Search.");
    printf("\n4.Delete");
    printf("\n5.Naa..");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice){
            case 1:printf("\nEnter element to add:");
                    scanf("%d",&val);
                    add(val);

                    //display();
                    break;
            case 2:display();
                    break;
            case 3:printf("\nEnter element to search for:");
                    scanf("%d",&val);
                    search(val);
                    break;

            case 4:printf("\nEnter element to Delete: ");
                    scanf("%d",&val);
                    deletei(val);
                    display();
                    break;
            case 5:return 0;

            }
    goto deci;
    return 0;
    }


    void add(int val){
    struct tnode * newnode=(struct tnode * )malloc(sizeof(struct tnode *));
    newnode->info=val;
    newnode->left=newnode->right=NULL;
    newnode->bf=0;//problem making,problem solved removing this statement
    if(root==NULL){
            root=newnode;

                    }                       
    else{
        struct tnode*tree=root;
        struct tnode*ptree=NULL;
    while(tree!=NULL){
                    if(val<tree->info){
                                        ptree=tree;
                                        tree=tree->left;

                    }
                    else{
                        ptree=tree;
                        tree=tree->right;
                    }                       


        }   
    if(val<ptree->info){

                ptree->left=newnode;
                tree=ptree->left;


        }
else{
ptree->right=newnode;   
tree=ptree->right;

    }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
struct tnode * newnode = (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode *))
```

From the [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) for `malloc`

> Allocates size bytes of uninitialized storage
>
> If allocation succeeds, returns a pointer to the lowest (first) byte in the allocated memory block

So `malloc` allocates a memory block and returns a pointer to the start of this block.
The argument to `malloc` is the size of the memory block you want to allocate.

In your case you are passing `sizeof(struct tnode *)`.
So you are allocating enough memory for a pointer to a value of type `struct tnode`.
If you want to allocate the memory for the `struct tnode` itself, change the `sizeof` to `sizeof(struct tnode)`.
Then the fixed line should look like

```
struct tnode * newnode = (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first main mistake is that you allocate a space only for an address for *newnode* in `add()`. You should convert it into:

```
struct tnode * newnode=(struct tnode * )malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
```

In this case you allocate an entire space for the required node.

PS. Please also resign from the 'goto' instruction as it is a bad practice to use it.

Comment: Thanks man..very stupid mistake I realize now...thanks for the help once again..will change the goto statement too...probabbly add while statement

Comment: No problem ;). Yes, the 'while' statement is better.